# Using re.split, how to return results as Integers and Strings

Tags: python, split, type-conversion

I'm having this simple code:

```
print( re.split(' |,', '156 for 23,5 or 15') )
# ['156', 'for', '23', '5', 'or', '15']
```

The question is how to return digits as integers and text as strings (it is already)... So getting this instead:

```
# [156, 'for', 23, 5, 'or', 15]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex, you can't.

However, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/2555451), and [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> import re
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.split(' |,', '156 for 23,5 or 15')]
[156, 'for', 23, 5, 'or', 15]
>>>
```